# Ul Li last element not aligning properly

Tags: css

I am having a problem where the last li element in a ul is pushing itself to the left further than the rest of all my pieces.  Attached is a screen shot and my code.

I have tried using the last-child element but it doesn't work in Safari or Chrome.

```
#attending ul {
 display: inline;
 margin: 0 5px 0 0;
 padding-left: 0px;
}
#attending ul li {
 display: inline;
 list-style-image:none;
 padding: 5px;

}
#attending li:last-child { 
    margin-right:-4px; 
  }
```

Suggestions?

http://desmond.yfrog.com/Himg338/scaled.php?tn=0&server=338&filename=screenshot20100526at808.jpg&xsize=640&ysize=640

---------------EDITED----------------

```
#attending {
width: 230px;
margin:0 13px 5px 12px;
float: left;
background-image: url(...);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
text-align:center;
height:360px;
overflow:hidden;
```

}

```
<div id="attending">
            <h2> Who's Attending <div id="eventtitle">Converge </div></h2>
                <ul>
                <li><a href='http://www.last.fm/user/IthisProtector' target='_blank'><img src='http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/34/30769977.jpg' alt='IthisProtector' height=40px; width=40px; style='border:0px;'/></a></li><li><a href='http://www.last.fm/user/Jordan1124' target='_blank'><img src='http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/34/46770143.jpg' alt='Jordan1124' height=40px; width=40px; style='border:0px;'/></a></li><li><a href='http://www.last.fm/user/redmedicine' target='_blank'><img src='http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/34/1612965.jpg' alt='redmedicine' height=40px; width=40px; style='border:0px;'/></a></li><li><a href='http://www.last.fm/user/phillstac3' target='_blank'><img src='http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/34/9373439.jpg' alt='phillstac3' height=40px; width=40px; style='border:0px;'/></a></li><li><a href='http://www.last.fm/user/hammajamma' target='_blank'><img src='http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/34/1577940.gif' alt='hammajamma' height=40px; width=40px; style='border:0px;'/></a></li><li><a href='http://www.last.fm/user/tastemaker' target='_blank'><img src='http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/34/31334281.jpg' alt='tastemaker' height=40px; width=40px; style='border:0px;'/></a></li><li><a href='http://www.last.fm/user/owlz' target='_blank'><img src='http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/34/38409251.jpg' alt='owlz' height=40px; width=40px; style='border:0px;'/></a></li><li><a href='http://www.last.fm/user/cersei' target='_blank'><img src='http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/34/16709925.png' alt='cersei' height=40px; width=40px; style='border:0px;'/></a></li><li><a href='http://www.last.fm/user/thenetsux' target='_blank'><img src='http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/34/46964551.jpg' alt='thenetsux' height=40px; width=40px; style='border:0px;'/></a></li><li><a href='http://www.last.fm/user/Shwang_Shwinga' target='_blank'><img src='http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/34/36391855.jpg' alt='Shwang_Shwinga' height=40px; width=40px; style='border:0px;'/></a></li><li><a href='http://www.last.fm/user/NightEndDay99' target='_blank'><img src='http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/34/23687175.jpg' alt='NightEndDay99' height=40px; width=40px; style='border:0px;'/></a></li><li><a href='http://www.last.fm/user/aliciabandee' target='_blank'><img src='http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/34/46562737.jpg' alt='aliciabandee' height=40px; width=40px; style='border:0px;'/></a></li><li><a href='http://www.last.fm/user/mcbaker2' target='_blank'><img src='http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/34/5005584.jpg' alt='mcbaker2' height=40px; width=40px; style='border:0px;'/></a></li><li><a href='http://www.last.fm/user/killcarriedeadd' target='_blank'><img src='http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/34/46160823.jpg' alt='killcarriedeadd' height=40px; width=40px; style='border:0px;'/></a></li><li><a href='http://www.last.fm/user/sexraptor89' target='_blank'><img src='http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/34/44930901.gif' alt='sexraptor89' height=40px; width=40px; style='border:0px;'/></a></li><li><a href='http://www.last.fm/user/Johnny_Acidtrip' target='_blank'><img src='http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/34/45211001.png' alt='Johnny_Acidtrip' height=40px; width=40px; style='border:0px;'/></a></li><li><a href='http://www.last.fm/user/chrismarzig' target='_blank'><img src='http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/34/41573869.jpg' alt='chrismarzig' height=40px; width=40px; style='border:0px;'/></a></li><li><a href='http://www.last.fm/user/Lapp0' target='_blank'><img src='http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/34/29210613.jpg' alt='Lapp0' height=40px; width=40px; style='border:0px;'/></a></li><li><a href='http://www.last.fm/user/iozephus' target='_blank'><img src='http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/34/46560555.jpg' alt='iozephus' height=40px; width=40px; style='border:0px;'/></a></li><li><a href='http://www.last.fm/user/JoshTheChaos' target='_blank'><img src='http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/34/41057871.jpg' alt='JoshTheChaos' height=40px; width=40px; style='border:0px;'/></a></li><li><a href='http://www.last.fm/user/ktdlmnop' target='_blank'><img src='http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/34/46312475.jpg' alt='ktdlmnop' height=40px; width=40px; style='border:0px;'/></a></li><li><a href='http://www.last.fm/user/RheannaReverie' target='_blank'><img src='http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/34/46435589.jpg' alt='RheannaReverie' height=40px; width=40px; style='border:0px;'/></a></li>                </ul>                
            </div>
```

Comment: You should also include the html. This should be easy to fix, but we need all the code to really help.

Comment: I've a hard time in visualizing this with help of the screenshot. Does the `#attending` have a fixed width? Is every image represented by a single `li` element? Or is it every row of images? Anyway, please edit and update your question to include some relevant HTML. Preferably a copy'n'paste'n'runnable example from `<html>` until with `</html>` (and doctype) which validates.

Comment: I'm not sure which doctype it is as its running wordpress.  Let me check that real quick.  

Here it is:

XHTML 1.0 Transitional

I guess I need to modify that to strict? no?

Comment: could it be that you have `text-align:center` on `#attending` or some parent element, which would make the `li` centered in the box (*since they are inline*) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your culprit is the `text-align:center` on the `#attending` css rule.

your `li`'s are centered since they have been converted to `inline`

***[update]***

ok, i had misunderstood the problem .. you need to remove the `5px` right margin from the `ul`  and it would center correctly..

here is the result **http://jsfiddle.net/uvXKb/**

Comment: How would I go about centering this then again?  I like the look of having it centered or is that just not possible?

Comment: @Chase just understood the problem ... remove the `5px` right-margin from the `ul` and it should center correctly..

Comment: Fixed it in firefox .. still issues in safari and chrome.

Comment: works fine in my chrome and safari ... check the link in my answer with the code .. (*the `last-child` rule could be remove completely..*)

Comment: Checked your code .. removed the last child rule and still no dice in chrome safari.

Comment: yes i have found a couple of more issues.. you seem to have hit a weird scenario of issues.. not sure if there is an all-browser-inclusive solution with CSS .. you might have to alter your html as well..

Comment: what about two last elements can they go to left somehow ?

Comment: @AXheladini you could just set the `text-align` to  `left` and make the container centered instead of the elements... demo at http://jsfiddle.net/HGavS/21/